# Getting this error InternalError while polling message from aws sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-sqs

Getting the following error, not frequently

InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.\n\tstatus code: 500, request id: d310d987-ef78-52be-8116-84e835c661cc]

What to do in this case, is there any way to check the status on aws console which sqs is behaving like this?

Comment: Where did the internal error originate? Can provide more code detailing how you've implemented the SQS polling?